# How to compile ROS messages "by hand"?

Tags: ros, message-generation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In our project, we use `SCons` as our build system. However, I compiled a `ROS` node (publisher) and try to integrate ROS as good as possible without `catkin`.

Now I need a custom message type and wonder, how the language-specific code is compiled from a `.msg` file? Which is the executable catkin calls to build the messages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187786/how-to-compile-ros-messages-%22by-hand%22?/) by [foopeter](https://answers.ros.org/users/18676/foopeter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-07-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-07-27**:
You could also create a dummy package and generate your messages there and copy them to your Ros node. The generated C++ messages will be in the dummy_pkg/include package, the Python messages will be under dummy_pkg/src/dummy_pkg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at [wiki/genmsg](http://wiki.ros.org/genmsg), it would seem that it invokes [github/gencpp](https://github.com/ros/gencpp), [github/genpy](https://github.com/ros/genpy) and any other message generators based on parameters supplied by some catkin / cmake macro wrappers.

I haven't done this myself, but I can imagine those generators can be invoked from a command line as well, provided you provide the proper arguments. The `genpy` readme even seems to give some hints about how to do that:

```
$ ./scripts/genmsg_py.py -p geometry_msgs -Istd_msgs:`rospack find std_msgs`/msg -Igeometry_msgs:`rospack find geometry_msgs`/msg -o gen `rospack find geometry_msgs`/msg/PoseStamped.msg
```

This can probably be integrated into a Scons build, by declaring the correct dependencies?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0